# SBT : Define different run profiles

Tags: scala, build, sbt

**tl;dr;**
Having two different execution modes. (1) is the normal run mode, (2) is a profiling mode which activates FlightRecorder. In (2) the javaOptions should just be enhanced.

**Long version**
Given that @Eugene Yokota proposed an answer I update the question w.r.t. the already provided answer.

My *build.sbt* currenty looks like the following:

```
lazy val Profile = config("profile") extend(Runtime)

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "org",
  version := "0.0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.0",
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-encoding", "utf8",
    "-deprecation",
    "-feature",
    "-language:dynamics",
    "-language:reflectiveCalls",
    "-language:postfixOps",
    "-language:implicitConversions",
    "-unchecked",
    "-target:jvm-1.8"),
  fork := true,
  javaHome := Some(file("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home")),
  javaOptions ++= Seq("-d64", "-Xms1024m", "-Xmx4048m")
)

lazy val main = (project in file("."))
  .configs(Profile)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "benchmark-scroll",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "xxx"
    )
  ).
  settings(inConfig(Profile)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    javaOptions ++= Seq(
      "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures", "-XX:+FlightRecorder",
      "-XX:StartFlightRecording=settings=profiling-expensive",
      "-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=."
    ))
  ): _*)
```

The proposed answer says that one now should be able to run with the new profile using `sbt "profile:run Benchmark"`.

Comment: I think that you can't change `SettingKey`s dinamically, like you can `TaskKey`s. Try something like `(javaOptions in profile) ++= { ...`. You can inspect it with `show profile::javaOptions` when in sbt shell.

Comment: show profile::javaOptions after your change shows the correct options. However, I normally run with `sbt "run Harness Benchmark"`, but when I type `sbt "profile Harness Benchmark"` it errors *[error] No valid parser available.
[error] profile Harness Benchmark*

Comment: You need to enclose the task's parameters in quotation marks, like `sbt profile "Harness Benchmark"`. See here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running.html#Batch+mode

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled that one. I thought that you already have a `Parser` defined. When a task has parameters, like `run` has, you need to define an `InputKey` for input task... But that's another question, see here for more info: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html